# Simple HTML Dom - Class attribute with more than one words and spaces

Tags: php, html, dom, domparser

I try to find that:

```
<a class="one two three four five">LINK</a>
```

What can I do to find anchors that contain in its class "four"?

I try in this way:

```
$dom->find("a[class*=four]");
```

But it doesn't work. I'm using the html_simple_dom library.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice right away that you meant not jQuery solution. Please check, I updated my answer.

Comment: According to the documentation, `[attribute*=value]` should work fine. Did you triple check that you are using the correct selector? How do you know that "it does not work"? `$dom->find("a.four")` should work too and if it does not, then your document is different than you think.

Comment: beacause `$dom->find("a[class*=four]");` return an array where count(array) = 0

Comment: What if you do `$dom->find("a")`, do you get all links? If yes, have a look which classes they have. I honestly think that your document is different...

Comment: Ok, the problem was that javascript set that class, so php can't able to found it.